# Stored procedure to get related elements

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures

I need to write stored procedures in my project.
I need to get the data from stored procedures and not directly from tables.

Now I have these two models:

```
public class Make
{
    public int ID { get; set; }        
    public string Name { get; set; }        
    public virtual ICollection<Model> Models { get; set; }        
}

public class Model
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int MakeID { get; set; }
    public string GroupName { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Engine> Engines { get; set; } 
}
```

My question is if I can write a stored procedure that gets all the Makes from DB, and to get all the related Models for every make.

This is the stored procedure that gets all the makes:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[sp_GetAllMakes] 
AS
SELECT
 MFA_ID = CONVERT(INT, MFA_ID),
 MFA_BRAND as Name
 FROM
  MANUFACTURERS
 ORDER BY
  MFA_BRAND
 ;
```

How can I modify this, to get the related model for every make? I have MODELS table in DB with MOD_MFA_ID as foreign key. 
Thanks in advance!

Comment: a simple `MANUFACTURERS INNER JOIN MODELS ON MODELS.MOD_MFA_ID = MANUFACTURERS.MFA_ID` isn't working ?

Comment: If I use this way, nothing happens. The result is the same. I need to get in the result, the related items.

Comment: SELECT
  MFA_ID = CONVERT(INT, MFA_ID),
  MFA_BRAND as Name
FROM
 MANUFACTURERS
 MANUFACTURERS INNER JOIN MODELS ON MODELS.MOD_MFA_ID = MANUFACTURERS.MFA_ID
 ORDER BY
 MFA_BRAND

Comment: Kindly specify data type of `MANUFACTURERS.MFA_ID`. I hope `MOD_MFA_ID` has the values from MANUFACTURERS.MFA_ID.

Comment: Side note: you should **not** use the `sp_` prefix for your stored procedures. Microsoft has [reserved that prefix for its own use (see *Naming Stored Procedures*)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190669%28v=sql.105%29.aspx), and you do run the risk of a name clash sometime in the future. [It's also bad for your stored procedure performance](http://www.sqlperformance.com/2012/10/t-sql-queries/sp_prefix). It's best to just simply avoid `sp_` and use something else as a prefix - or no prefix at all!

Comment: The data type of MFA_ID is 
    [MFA_ID]       SMALLINT     NOT NULL. Yes, the MOD_MFA_ID has the values from Manufacturers.MFA_ID. Maybe the inner join would be enough to get the data that I want, but in another way..... I don't have too much experience with stored procedures

Comment: If you are only getting data and not modifying data, then you should use a view, not a stored procedure.